# int -> ('a -> 'a)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

I have a question that I came across studying SML. It requires the return type to be int -> (’a -> ’a). This is what I have done:

```
- fn x:int => fn y => y;
val it = fn : int -> 'a -> 'a
```

How can I make the return type to be int -> ('a -> 'a) where 'a -> 'a is in brackets? Any help would be appreciated, I have been trying it figure it out for hours and can't find anything related to it here or searching on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A -> B -> C` and `A -> (B -> C)` are the same type. The `->` operator in types is right associative.

By convention the type checker doesn't print redundant parentheses, so you'll never see `int -> ('a -> 'a)` printed for your code.

You're already done. :-)

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!